# Internet Explorer 9 crashes with "Debug Error" on new Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I recently reformatted my computer. And whenever I right click on Internet Explorer 9 (No-addons), this error always appears:

```
MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ DEBUG LIBRARY
Debug Error
Program:/C:/Windows/ExplorerEXE
Module:/C:/Program Files (x86)/EgisTec/MyWinLocker 3/x64/mwl shell ext.dll
File:Run Time Check Failure #2-Stack around the variable 'sz Temp' was corrupted.
(Press retry to debug the application)
```

There are no programs installed because it is newly reformatted and my Windows is up to date. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Internet Explorer, reformatting my computer again, running a disk check, running commands such as `sfc /scannow` but still no luck.

[image: Screenshot of error]

My computer specs are:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- i3 processor
- 4 GB RAM

Comment: Will you perhaps consider changing the title to a more meaningful one?

Answer (score 6):

Update MyWinLocker program or uninstall it. I have this issue with 1password.

Although you say you haven't installed anything, it looks like MyWinLocker from EgisTec has installed a shell extension that is crashing. This doesn't come standard with Windows, so if you didn't install it then it must be baked into the Windows 7 install media you're using.

If you uninstall it, whatever the problem is should go away and will confirm that is the culprit. Hopefully the vendor can provide a version that doesn't crash Explorer.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the addition to my answer. I have been laid up in the hospital after surgery and was having issues expanding on my answer.